# how to address a child element in a div, addressed by its index

Tags: jquery

To address an element by its index is clear:

```
inner= $("span.[class*="myClass"]")[indTextTitle].innerHTML;
```

now, I have some div containing a I'ld like ta adress

```
<div class='row'><a class'title'> ... </a>...<p class='this'></p></div>
<div class='row'><a class'text'> ... </a>...<p class='that'></p></div>
<div class='row'><a class'title'> ... </a>...<p class='more'></p></div>
```

a function is clalled when clicked a link

```
$(function() { $("a.title").click(function(){
var indTitle = $("a.title").index(this); 
var Index =   $($("a.title")[indTitle]).parents("div.row").index();
```

What must be stupidly simple is to adress one of the p - elements by the index of the div:

```
inner = S("div.row[index] p").innerHTML.
```

However, I'm more stupid. I've checked lots of ways, nothing worked once the brackets of the index appear. Again, no problem to adress the p.this[xy].innerHTML directly. But its index is changed dynamically and the only logical access is the index of the div.

Thanks for any help

Thomas

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function or the [:eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)-selector as `$('a.title:eq(1)')` or `$('a.title').eq(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

By index, try:

```
inner = $($("div.row")[Index]).find('p').html();
```

Alternatively, since the `p` element you are interested in appears to always be the last child of `div.row`, you could try:

```
inner = $(this).parent().find('p:last').html();
```

assuming that `inner` is defined in the click handler for the `a`.

Comment: inner = $($("div.row")[Index]).find('p').html();

there was just one bracket too much [index]) instead of [index]))